# Errors creating a library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
I have created and imported a library .AAR package.

1) It is included in a settings.gradle file

2) and in the dependencies in build.gradle using implementation is not compile.

3)have debug{} and release{} in buildTypes in the gradle file but i am still getting errors.

Comment: Show your logcat

Comment: Check the folder of your application using windows explorer, see is there your library folder<Library name> available, inside which there should be a build.gradle and .aar file .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've run into errors related to dependency matching. Read the guide and follow the migration instructions in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#resolve_matching_errors).